# How can I save string value to sql server db datatype as time(7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, timespan

I have to save a time to sqlserver2008 db as `time(7)` data type which is in string format in code behind.how can I convert it to that data type.My code getting error

```
string time='9.30 pm';
modal db=new modal();
db.time=Timespan.Parse(time);
context.modal.Add(db);
context.SaveChanges();
```

in db,time as `time(7)` datatype

error is

> An exception of type `'System.FormatException'` occurred in `mscorlib.dll` but was not handled in user code.   Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

Comment: Your code shouldn't _even_ compile. `'9.30 pm'` needs double quotes. What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: `Timespan` is a duration of time, not a time of day.  So instead of "9:30 pm" you'd need "21:30".

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - check the Remarks section to see what string formats are acceptable by `Timespan.Parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661232/how-do-i-convert-a-12-hour-time-string-into-a-c-sharp-timespan), you can do this:

```
string time="9.30 pm";
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "h.mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

db.time = Timespan.Parse(ts);
context.modal.Add(db);
context.SaveChanges();
```