# how to parse time in timespan which is in hh:mm:ss tt format in c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I have string which contain `h:mm:ss tt` format time, I want to convert this string to timespan

I tried below

```
 string time = "5:49:41 PM";
 TimeSpan Reportingtime = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
```

But it gets error that `String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.`

Please Help me

Comment: In the line of time, `DateTime` is a point while `TimeSpan` is a segment. You need another point, because two points make a line segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like it is decripted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661232/how-do-i-convert-a-12-hour-time-string-into-a-c-sharp-timespan) Post

```
string s = "5:19:41 PM";
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
//if you really need a TimeSpan this will get the time elapsed since midnight:
TimeSpan ts = t.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I would vote this up, except it is just a copy of the linked answer. It would be better if you could produce something new and useful on your own.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure a solution is posted, even if the link I referenced maybe is broken someday. And I couldn't think of a better way doing this.

Comment: @croxy- Thanks, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

With this common time format, it could be reduced to:

```
string time = "5:19:41 PM";
TimeSpan reportingTime = DateTime.Parse(time).TimeOfDay;
```